# Liftings incoherent diagrams of derivators using their incoherent images, to define morphisms

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\def\D{\mathbb D}\def\E{\mathbb E}$Lately, I've been thinking about derivators a lot: a positive answer to the following question would make several problems fall at once.

Assume you want to define a functor $F : {\cal C}\to \cal D$: sometimes, it is very easy to say that $FC$ is equal to the co/limit of a certain diagram obtained in $\cal D$, maybe via another functor in the opposite direction; this construction often yields an adjuction.

> Is there any hope to recover this procedure in the world of pre/derivators?

Assume I have two derivators $\D,\E$ and I want to define a morphism $G : \D \to \E$ on components; assume that (for example) I have an object $X\in\D(J)$, and I can build out of it an incoherent diagram $X_\circ \in\E(J)^\rightrightarrows$; I'm tempted to define $G_J(X) = \text{holim }\tilde{X}$, where $\tilde X$ is a lifting of $X_\circ$ to $\E(J\times\rightrightarrows)$ such that $\text{dia}_\rightrightarrows(\tilde X) = X_\circ$.

I see three problems:

1. this construction relies on essential surjectivity properties of the $\text{dia}_\rightrightarrows$ functor: it obviously becomes unreasonable if I replace $\rightrightarrows$ with another shape. But does it work with equalizer shapes, at least (and dually, taking hocolim's, does it work with coequalizer shapes)?
2. Is $\tilde X$ unique up-to-something? Guess: no. Somehow, asking that amounts to ask the $\text{dia}$ functor to be a [smothering](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smothering+functor) functor.
3. Even assuming it is, how can I be sure that the components $G_J$ glue to a morphism of prederivators? Of course, in general I can't. But what are sufficient conditions ensuring it, then?

Comment: The object $\tilde X$ will be well defined, as it only depends on the homotopy classes of the maps defining the coequalizer diagram, but this construction doesn't define a functor by the same reason that mapping cones do not define a functor on a triangulated category (mapping cones are homotopy coequalizers where one of the arrows is null).

Comment: To flesh out Fernando's comment, $\tilde X$ is unique up to a non-unique isomorphism mapping to the identity under dia, using fullness. I don't see the relationship to smotheringness, which is only different from the usual assumptions on dia in that it asks for strict surjectivity on objects.

Comment: Thanks! This is not bad news. I have to see how unique I need $\tilde X$ in order to do what I have in mind. But now I feel compelled to ask if there's a reference about $\text{dia}_\rightrightarrows$ being full and essentially surjective.

Comment: @KevinCarlson - the nLab page refers to "the usual assumptions on dia" as "weakly smothering", as opposed to (strictly) smothering which is strictly surjective on objects.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian while I don't know what you're trying to do, in general my experience is that in this situation you should instead construct a *particular* coherent diagram $\tilde{X}$ and define $G_J(X)$ to be its (co)limit.  For instance, to define the cofiber of a coherent arrow $f \in D(2)$ with underlying incoherent arrow $x \to y$, you shouldn't think about "lifting the incoherent span $0 \leftarrow x \to y$ to a coherent one", instead you should think about "extending the coherent arrow $f$ to a coherent span" -- in this case, by Kan extending along the inclusion of an arrow into a span.

Comment: @MikeShulman Yep, I agree-that's what I meant to be saying with my comment, which may have been unclear.